# wordpress gravity form xml

Tags: xml, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to create some software in VB (.Net) that takes a .txt file, and converts it into a .xml file that can be imported into Gravity Forms plugin in Wordpress.

Could someone give me an example .xml file for a contact form that Wordpress/Gravity forms will accept?

Thanks!
Marie

Comment: I have created a field for time (so the type="time") but I want it to record seconds, tenths and hundredths of seconds. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: http://pastie.org/9676594

Please note in Gravity Forms 1.9 which is currently in beta we have changed the import/export format to JSON. Exporting of forms to XML is no longer possible. Importing of XML files is not being deprecated in 1.9 as it is still needed to allow the import of legacy XML files.

Comment: I have created a field for time (so the type="time") but I want it to record mins, seconds, tenths and hundredths. How do I do that?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use a Time field for this. You would either need to use individual text or number fields for each part or you could create your own custom field. The following tutorial shows how you can get started creating a custom field: http://wpsmith.net/2011/plugins/how-to-create-a-custom-form-field-in-gravity-forms-with-a-terms-of-service-form-field-example/

Comment: The following explains how you can create a multi-input field so Gravity Forms will save the values for each input: http://theagencyonline.co.uk/2014/07/custom-multiple-input-form-for-gravity-fields/